# Can I use .size() in .removeif() as a conditional with ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist

In the program I am writing I would like to remove doubles from an ArrayList if they are less than a certain value. However if only one element is left, even if it meets the condition to be removed, I do not want to remove it as I need that Arraylist to not be empty.

I saw in the javadoc for ArrayLists that there is a `removeIf(filter)` method, so tentatively I've written this:

```java
employeeLine.removeIf(customerTime -> (customerTime < nextCustomerArrival && employeeLine.size() > 1));
```

So for example, if `nextCustomerArrival = 11.0` and `employeeLine = [2.0, 5.0, 8.5]`, then after using what I wrote I would like to see `employeeLine = [8.5]`. However, this line is part of a much larger class that I'm writing and I'm not sure how to readily check if this would work or not. Any help would be great.

Edit1: Fixed the typo pointed out by moilejter; thanks mate.

Edit2: I have tried compiling this and get the following error:

```
MultiLaneSimulation.java:66: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
                        lines.get(j).removeIf(customer -> (customer < sequentialArrivalTime && lines.get(j).size() > 1));
                                                                                                         ^
1 error
```

So, no dice. Additionally, I tried testing this in a test code's main method and it would remove all of the elements instead of all but one. I then tried a for-each loop but that leads me to getting a `Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, so no dice again.

At this point I'm just gonna try writing a helper-method that does what I want. If I manage to figure it out, I'll post it as an answer for others/ if you are curious.

Edit3: For context, I am essentially using these ArrayLists as a sorted Queue (first = smallest --> last = largest), so I am only ever going to be interested in keeping the last element if this situation occurs.

P.S. Pre-Emptive Apology: I am a first-time Poster to SO and would call myself a Java novice. If I say or try something that doesn't make sense, I swear I'm not trying to confuse you or piss you off, I'm just still learning.

Comment: compile and check. this should work.

Comment: Can't imagine why not..  Go for it and see.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: If I understood you right, you meant to write employeeLine.size() in there, right?  I suspect this would be a bad idea, in general - but I don't know if this is safe.  Wouldn't it be better to select which one you would need to pick, if you had to, then remove all the ones that match your criteria - and then add the selected one, if your list rurned out to be empty?  I am thinking it might be easier to read, and it would let you describe how you would pick the one value to keep, if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the pseudocode for your conditions,

1) Save the lastElement in the List to a temporary variable.

2) remove all elements < minimumAllowedValue

3) If, all elements are removed, we need to add the temporary value saved in Step 1.

```
public static void removeLessThan(Double minimumAllowedValue, ArrayList<Double> list) {
        Double lastElement = list.get(list.size() - 1); //Assuming List is not empty and contains atleast 1 element.
        list.removeIf(element -> element < minimumAllowedValue);
        if(list.isEmpty()) {
         list.add(lastElement);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As promised, I was able to write a helper method that does what I was looking for. I'm sure there exists a better/more reliable/more robust/etc. solution out there but hey, it's past midnight right now so I will take what I can get. Below is my creation:

```
    /**
    * Removes doubles from an ArrayList that are strictly less than the given parameter
    * NOTE: leaves the last element if this would reduce the ArrayList.size() to 0
    *
    * @param minimumAllowedValue  Of type Double; remaining values in the ArrayList will be greater than or equal to it
    * @param list  Of type ArrayList<Double>; the ArrayList we are changing
    */
    public static void removeLessThan(Double minimumAllowedValue, ArrayList<Double> list) {
        ArrayList<Double> toRemove = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (Double element : list) {
            if (element < minimumAllowedValue) {
                toRemove.add(element);
            }
        }
        if (toRemove.size() == list.size()) {
            toRemove.remove(list.size() - 1);
        }
        list.removeAll(toRemove);
    }
```